# How do you communicate with the activity view model (in app module) from a feature module?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, multi-module

I need to store a state from a Fragment to persist even when the Fragment is popped. It needs to last until the app is killed.

I was thinking of having the Fragment store this into its Activity View Model. However, the main Activity View Model is in the app module and the Fragment is in a feature module.

How is a Fragment in the feature module meant to get its Activity View Model in the app module, when a feature module should not depend on the app module?

There also might be another way of having this state persist through the whole app that might be better instead of trying to communicate with the parent Activity View Model.

Comment: According to this codelab, you should create the viewModel in the Fragment but attach it to the activity's lifecycle scope by using `by activityViewModels()` https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#4